# Prevent JSP from caching values

Tags: java, jsp, caching, struts-1

I am facing problem of caching when using JSP. My application is made up of struts and jsp.
Practically in my application struts action class and JSP page is being used for adding and editing data.

The sequence of action that takes place are as follow:

1. User login into application
2. User visits the JSP page(PreNeed.jsp) containing form to fill up.
3. User fill in details and clicks on save button.

Now assume user had checked "Pre-Need Serviced" radio button and submitted form as shown in below screenshot.

But next time when user goes and tries to fill in form and clicks on save button then it automatically tries to save as "Pre-Need Serviced" even though user is not touched that section.

I feel page is caching values.

I tried putting below scriplet in JSP page:

```
<%        
    response.setHeader("Pragma", "No-cache");
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
    response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);
%>
```

But does not worked out. Is there any specific position this code needs to be placed ?

EDIT:
Here is my JSP code

```
<td id="_preneedStatus">
    <logic:notEqual name="preNeed" property="posted" value="1">
        <html:radio value="Active" name="preNeed" property="preneedStatus"/>
        <font face="Arial" size="2">Pre-Need Active</font><br>
    </logic:notEqual>
    <html:radio value="Serviced" name="preNeed"  property="preneedStatus"/>
    <font face="Arial" size="2">Pre-Need Serviced</font><br>
    <logic:equal name="accoutDescDisplay" scope="session" value="display">
        <font face="Arial" size="2">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Service Date:&nbsp;</font>
                <html:text size="10" name="preNeed" property="serviceDate" onblur="setDispositionDate();" onfocus="focusDateEdit(this);" />
                <fdms:FDMSDate fieldID="serviceDate1" javascriptFormField="document.forms[0].serviceDate"></fdms:FDMSDate>
        <br/>       
    </logic:equal>
    <logic:notEqual name="preNeed" property="posted" value="1">
        <html:radio value="Cancelled"  name="preNeed" property="preneedStatus"/>
        <font face="Arial" size="2">Pre-Need Cancelled</font>
    </logic:notEqual>
</td>
```

**Browser For testing:** Firefox, Chrome

**Framework:** Struts 1.2

**Server:** Wildfly 9.0.1.Final(JBoss)

Please guide me on the same.
[image]

Comment: I think you should create the constructor or reset method like set default for that page

Comment: Which Struts version? Show your code.

Comment: @AleksandrM struts version is 1.2

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you've actually tried up to this point, and I'm also not sure what browser you're working in, but have you tried anything along these lines in your JSP file:

```
<%
response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-cache"); 
response.setHeader("Pragma","no-cache"); 
response.setDateHeader ("Expires", -1); 
%>
```

It seems to be a common answer to caching issues. However, this will most likely also get rid of *all* caching, so it's probably not exactly what you're looking for.

Sources:

- http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0590.html
- http://www.xyzws.com/jspfaq/how-to-disable-browser-caching-for-a-specific-jsp/11

Comment: is there any specific position within JSP page this code needs to be placed ?

Comment: I'd guess not, since the response won't be sent back until the entire JSP has been rendered. It might make most sense near the top of the document for clarity sake.

Comment: You might want to read this little blog too on [_cache control headers_](http://www.mobify.com/blog/beginners-guide-to-http-cache-headers/). Might make the whole thing a little clearer.

Comment: I see you've added this to your answer above. Sorry they didn't work for you. Have you verified that they are actually in the response being returned to your browser? There should be a Networking view of some sort in your web browser's Developer Tools.

Comment: Yes in the Response Header section in console I could see those parameters.

Comment: Hey, can you try out what's written [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24481871/how-to-disallow-caching-in-struts2) and see if that works. It's a little bit more complicated, but only slightly.

Comment: Sure I'll just implement that and let you know

Comment: But I am just wondering how it is caching only that field. However there are lot of fields form has. its strange.

Comment: Just in case I don't answer your question, you really should post the JSP file in your question along with what browser you are testing this in, the version of the frameworks you are using, what server you are hosting your site on (Tomcat, Jetty), and the version of that server.

Comment: Here is my last guess. I found another post on stack overflow regarding radio buttons specifically : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8254094/can-radio-buttons-be-empty-after-refreshing-a-page

Comment: so you mean to say I supposed to mark `checked=false` in radio button at the begining. Am I correct ?

Comment: Mike I tried marking radio button false on refresh but it will not show up selected value once I submit data as page gets refreshed upon submit

Comment: Sorry, I'm not an expert in web. Those were just solutions based on the information you gave. Im all out of ideas. Good luck.